# Using TinyMCE with Fancybox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce, fancybox, tinymce-4

I have an application which uses plugins. These plugins will have their own controllers, razor views, etc. I am using Fancybox from the main application to load some of the partial views by ajax into a popup. Works great. Problem I have now is with trying to apply tiny MCE to a textarea inside fancybox. The textareas in the plugins all have to specify a css class name if they want to be rich text. In this case, `kx-richtext`.

**Partial View:**

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BodyContent)
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.BodyContent, new { @class = "kx-richtext" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BodyContent)
    </div>
```

**Fancybox:**

This is my Fancybox config on the `_Layout.cshtml` page in the main app.

```
$('[data-toggle="lightbox"]').fancybox({
    type: 'ajax',
    autoSize: false,
    scrolling: 'yes',
    autoHeight: true,
    minHeight: 250,
    iframe: {
        scrolling: 'auto',
        preload: false
    },
    beforeLoad: function () {
        var width = this.element.data('fancybox-width');
        if (width) {
            this.width = parseInt(width);
        }

        var height = this.element.data('fancybox-height');
        if (height) {
            this.height = parseInt(height);
        }

        if (this.type == "iframe") {
            this.padding = 0;
        }
    },
    afterLoad: function () {
        initRichTextFull();
        //tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, ".kx-richtext");
        //tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, ".kx-richtext");
    }
});
```

**TinyMCE Config**

```
function initRichTextFull() {
                tinymce.init({
                    selector: "textarea.kx-richtext",
                    theme: "modern",
                    plugins: [
                        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
                        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
                        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
                        "emoticons template paste textcolor"
                    ],
                    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
                    toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
                    image_advtab: true,
                    templates: [
                        { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
                        { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
                    ]
                });
            }
```

The above tinymce config works perfectly fine if not using fancybox OR if I copy and paste the tinymce config into the partial view itself in the plugin. However, I cannot actually accept that as a solution.. as I need to apply the tinymce config from the main app only.

I can see that the Fancybox `afterLoad` function is being called, but it doesn't seem to do anything with regards to tinymce.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I have a good solution: just use `EditorTemplates`. I ended up doing the following:

Add this on the model property:

```
[UIHint("RichTextEditorFull")]
```

Then use `EditorFor` instead of `TextAreaFor` in the plugins and finally:

Create the `RichTextEditorFull` editor template in the main application

In my case:

```
@{
    string fieldName = @ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty);
    string value = (string)ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue;
}

@Html.TextArea(string.Empty, value)

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea#@fieldName",
            theme: "modern",
            plugins: [
                "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
                "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
                "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
                "emoticons template paste textcolor"
            ],
            toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
            toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
            image_advtab: true,
            templates: [
                { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
                { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

As simple as that.